# CODENAME ONE - Download link in BrowserComponent not working. On click nothing happens. In other browsers working fine

Tags: browser, download, permissions, storage, codenameone

i use BrowserComponent in order to packing a website in my codename one app. I build it for android, but when i click any download link nothing happens. Download don't start. does anyone know how to fix? In other browser working fine ok.

I build my codename one app for android. When i install it, no authoritazion o permission are requested. In the app there is only a form with browserComponent that call a website. The download links in the website not working in Codenameone's browserComponent .

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58450274/browsercomponent-ondownloadstart-event

Comment: Thanks Shai. 

I see this:

bc.addBrowserNavigationCallback(url -> {
    // *** WARNING: this code runs off the EDT and must not block!!!! ***
    if(shouldIDownloadThisURL(url) {
        String file = getStorageFileNameForUrl(url);
        Util.downloadUrlToStorageInBackground(url, file, 
           ev -> fileDownloadCompleted(file));
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}); 

but i do not find this methods:

shouldIDownloadThisURL

getStorageFileNameForUrl

fileDownloadCompleted

can I intercept the download in other ways?

Comment: That's a method you need to implement to indicate if you want to download that specific URL.