Download PDF Failing
The following urls set in the BrowserComponent uses JavaScript to converts HTML to a PDF which can be downloaded by clicking a button.
This works in a web browser, but it doesn't download in Codename One simulator or app installed in a device.
Form form = new Form("Generate Pdf", new BorderLayout());
BrowserComponent browser = new BrowserComponent();

browser.setURL("https://coltish-stoppering.000webhostapp.com/GeneratePdf.html");
//browser.setURL("https://coltish-stoppering.000webhostapp.com/GeneratePdfPdfMake.html");

browser.addWebEventListener("onLoad", (e) -> {
    form.revalidate();
});
form.add(CENTER, browser);
form.show();

Is there any setting required in the BrowserComponent for download to work?

See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58450274/browsercomponent-ondownloadstart-event

This works if pdf url is  like https://example.com/PdfName.pdf. If I implement this using urls above, it downloads a html page (text/html). Even if the downloaded file has .pdf extension,  it doesn't open since it's not a valid pdf, it's a text/html

In my case, pdf is created and downloaded after clicking buttons after the page has completely loaded.

For that you would need to inject some JavaScript to detect the right events in which this is ready.

The problem with jspdf & html2canvas libraries used in urls above is that they don't let user to specify where to save the generated pdf file. By default, they save the generated file to Downloads directory. If they allowed one to save to a specific directory on the server, I would create a url to download the file using Util
